# How to send a CW1 hyperlink in MS Teams

Tags: hyperlink, microsoft-teams

I am not able to share hyperlinks to CW1 modules in MS Teams. I have however noticed that many other people can.

Steps I have followed are:

1. Click in the CW1 module that I want to create a hyperlink for
2. Paste the content into MS Teams
3. Send the content to my MS Teams contact.

Note1: In step 2, if the content you have pasted into MS Teams is not blue and underlined, then a hyperlink is not created.

Note2: I am able to paste hyperlinks into MS WORD, MS OUTLOOK - just not MS Teams.
When doing this I can see that the  (Press 'CTRL+H' and pasting

Answer (score 0):

To generate CW1 URLs for pasting into MS Teams do the following:

1. Copy and paste the following text into a file and save as `clipboard_ediprod.ps1` on your Desktop or anywhere convenient.

> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")  $linkName =
> Get-Clipboard  $rawLink = Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Rtf
> $rawLink[2] -match '"(.*)"'  $ediprodLink = $Matches[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kc9Y.png)  Write-Host
> $ediprodLink  $ediprodLink =
> [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($ediprodLink)  $htmlContent = '[{1}](http://sydco-wpdl-2:5000/%7B0%7D)' -f $ediprodLink,$linkName
> Set-Clipboard -Value $htmlContent -AsHtml

2. Right click on that file and create a shortcut
3. Edit the shortcut and change the Target to one that is convenient/accessible for you. Ensure the following text precedes your file name. Note that the full file path must be in double quotes:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
> -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\jane.doe\OneDrive - WiseTech Global Pty Ltd\Desktop\clipboard_ediprod.ps1"

4. Save shortcut and then right click on it and choose “Pin to taskbar”
5. You should now see something like this:

[image: powershell icon]

6. To use it, just press "CTRL+H" in an CW1 object to place the special url into the clipboard
7. Then click on the icon in the taskbar and it will convert the link into something that you can paste directly into Teams.

Comment: If possible, Could you please video recording or screenshots?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on CW1 URL and share the screenshots/Video recording?

Comment: We tried to repro the scenario, But unable to repro the scenario. attached video. Could you please share video if I am doing wrong?Here i am not able to Pin to taskbar.
https://youtu.be/Mi9VbZ8FmaA